# Wording of upvote/downvote tooltips and FAQ on Meta sites

Tags: discussion, voting, meta, tooltips

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change upvote/downvote tooltip on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites)

On Meta sites, the upvote tooltip text reads "This answer is useful" and the downvote text reads "This answer is not useful". However those people familiar with Meta know that this isn't really true. As described on the [Meta SO FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), "voting is used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness".

Should the upvote/downvote text be changed for Meta sites to something more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion**

Upvote - I agree with this answer

Downvote - I don't agree with this answer

I considered using the word "support" instead of "agree" as well, which may be better as it probably applies in more instances.