# Change the tooltip for voting buttons on meta

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change upvote/downvote tooltip on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites)

If, as is frequently claimed, voting on meta sites indicates agreement or disagreement, would it be possible to change the tooltip to say "I agree with this" and "I don't agree with this" instead of the current "This is useful" and "This is not useful"?

It seems like that would help reinforce the intent and meaning of votes on the meta sites.

Comment: I'm almost positive this is a dupe.

Comment: It's in the FAQ now: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: Closing this doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: @pavium: It's not being closed to solve the problem. It's being closed because it's a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, but I see no evidence the problem is being addressed. Maybe it's not really a problem -- there have been no other votes in 2 hours.