# Can we get different "Voting-Tooltips" for Meta-Sites?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change upvote/downvote tooltip on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites)

As we all know, downvoting expresses something different on Meta-Sites, this is correctly reflected in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Can you change the tooltips of the voting arrows to express that, too?

[image: Simple showoff of my art skills!]