# Tool tip on voting in meta discussion is inaccurate

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change upvote/downvote tooltip on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites)

The tool tip for down voting on meta states:

> This answer is not useful

But I understand as meta QA can be closer to a discussion where down votes are supposed to represent a disagreement with a point of view, surely the tool tip should be something like:

> This answer is not useful or you disagree with this point

or if a discussion tag exists

> You disagree with this point

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites

Comment: The tooltip is mostly guidance for new users. In practice, users can (and do) use votes for any reason they see fit, as long as it's not abusive (i.e. serial voting).