# Down/up vote tooltips should speak differently on meta

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta, tooltips

As more experienced users know, [votes work differently on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). However, the tooltips still say the same as on other StackExchange sites:

[image]

The tooltips are:

- Question up vote: *This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear*.
- Question down vote: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*.
- Answer up vote: *This answer is useful*.
- Answer down vote: *This answer is not useful*.

I think the tooltips should be fixed on meta to speak their actual meaning.

Although I understand *why* the votes have different meaning on Meta, it is quite a bad practice to change the expected behaviour of already established elements. In this situation maximum should be done to correct for this bad practice; either by 
some notifications to the new user, pop-ups, ... Fixing wrong tooltips is the absolute minimum that should surely be done in this regard.

Comment: They don't always have a different meaning. I vote up or down for the usual reasons most of the time.

Comment: Declined, but related:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites?rq=1

Comment: @LBT That is a duplicate, not just related I believe.

Comment: +1 for the recursion...

Comment: You have not dissapointed me @user000001, I hoped somebody will like it! ;-) They have broken it a bit; hope someone will not even edit the question :-)

Comment: @Asad duplicates of declined questions with so many upvotes should be reviewed from time to time :-)

Comment: @Tomas I absolutely agree. That doesn't change the fact that this is a dupe though.

Comment: @Tomas Fixed the recursion for you :)

Comment: @Asad not by downvoting!!! ;-)