# Voting arrow descriptors indicate agreement/disagreement for meta feature requests?

Tags: feature-request

This [question has been asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202755/change-misleading-tooltip-for-feature-request-questions), but the suggested feature request wording was not specified. I am suggesting a three word addition to the voting icon descriptor:

Something as simple as appending "feature request agreement/disagreement"

- "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear;
  feature request agreement" and
- "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or
  not useful; feature request disagreement"?

It would be great to see the voting arrow descriptors indicate that on meta the votes indicate "agreement/disagreement". [This information is available in the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

...but it would be useful to have it right at the point of action:
[image]
[image]